# Pepper robot: where I can download "The Auto Recharging App"

Tags: pepper

I want to setup automatic charging station, in the Pepper page, there is no button to setup  auto recharging station. so in the Charging Station Guide, they said I should go to app store to install the auto recharging app, however I did not find it. My Pepper is Naoqi 2.5. I have no idea where I can find this app.
link: https://cloud.aldebaran-robotics.com/

Can anyone know?

Comment: In our case, we had to ask the SoftBank support to install the `autonomous-recharge` app. After they set it up in the cloud, the application was downloaded to Pepper via the update check.

Comment: If u have Command Centre access, then You can install app from the Softbank Robotic's Command Centre. If else contact support team.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I have contacted them, and waiting for their response. Seems it is really slow...

Comment: @androider I used Pepper Naoqi 2.5, I donot have command center access.

Comment: 5days left, I still did not get support team feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you purchased a NAOqi 2.5 Pepper with a recharge pod, you should have access to the app `autonomous-recharge` at https://cloud.aldebaran-robotics.com/ when logged in with your SoftBank Robotics account.

If you do not find it, they probably made a mistake and you did well by contacting them.

Comment: I have gotten the contact and install this app.